# How to write javascript in client side to receive and parse `chunked` response in time?

Tags: ajax, chunked

I'm using play framework, to generate chunked response. The code is:

```
class Test extends Controller {
    public static void chunk() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String data = repeat("" + i, 1000);
            response.writeChunk(data);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use browser to visit `http://localhost:9000/test/chunk`, I can see the data displayed increased every second. But, when I write a javascript function to receive and handle the data, found it will block until all data received.

The code is:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax(
        "/test/chunked", 
        {
            "success": function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

I can see a message box popped up after 10s, when all the data received.

How to get the stream and handle the data in time?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support that, but you can do that with plain XHR:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET", "/test/chunked", true)
xhr.onprogress = function () {
  console.log("PROGRESS:", xhr.responseText)
}
xhr.send()
```

This works in [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2), including IE 10. W3C specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#arraybuffer-response-entity-body).

The downside here is that `xhr.responseText` contains an accumulated response. You can use substring on it, but a better idea is to use the [responseType](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-responsetype-attribute) attribute and use `slice` on an `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: why is using of ArrayBuffer better?

Comment: @4esn0k: for example if you decide to use a binary protocol, which is a good idea. Another point here is that browser doesn't have to keep the entire data in memory, and as far as i understand, it's easier to achieve with `ArrayBuffer` than with a `String`. `slice` should work better, since it doesn't have to work with UTF-8 String as `substring` does, but can just use array indexes.

Comment: @4esn0k `moz-chunked-text` looks very promising, but is only available in FF and unfortunately isn't a part of XMLHttpRequest2 spec, so it's unlikely to be implemented in other browsers sometimes soon.

Comment: is there a more structured approach / better library to do that?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275128/jquery-ajax-extension-xdomainrequest-onprogress)

Comment: @Edmondo1984, I ended up creating this package which allows more efficient tranfer than jsonpipe: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chunked-request

Comment: @JonnyReeves do you have benchmarks for chunked-request vs. jsonpipe? What makes it more efficient - the ability to pass in a custom chunk parser?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing as OP asked. I followed Phil's directions and getting the response in chunks. But What should I do to NOT accumulate response? I tried to set responseType to arraybuffer but then I do not get any response.

Comment: I found it helpful to wrap the xhr request in an ajax request because rails automatically includes the CSRF token in AJAX requests.

Comment: @philpirozhkov Can you please provide an example with `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` ?

Comment: @philpirozhkov Just checked [specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-response-attribute) and it seems like `response` will be `null` until xhr is done in case  `responseType = "arraybuffer"`

Answer (score 7):

Soon we should be able to use `ReadableStream` API ([MDN docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream)). The code below seems to be working with Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94:

```
fetch(url).then(function (response) {
    let reader = response.body.getReader();
    let decoder = new TextDecoder();
    return readData();
    function readData() {
        return reader.read().then(function ({value, done}) {
            let newData = decoder.decode(value, {stream: !done});
            console.log(newData);
            if (done) {
                console.log('Stream complete');
                return;
            }
            return readData();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: above code worked nicely. Had to add check before 'let newData = decoder' that 'value' was not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

the `success` event would fire when the complete data transmission is done and the connection closed with a 200 response  code.  I believe you should be able to implement a native `onreadystatechanged` event and see the data packets as they come.

Comment: `onreadystatechanged` will only fire on timeout, abort and successfull request done. It won't fire on chunks.

Comment: `onreadystatechange` is called each time the `readystate` property changes.