# jQuery $.ajax extension XDomainRequest onprogress

Tags: javascript, jquery, xdomainrequest

**The short version:**

I want to get [this](https://github.com/kpozin/jquery-ajaxprogress#readme) to work with [this](https://github.com/Ovea/cors/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/ovea/cors/jquery.ie.cors.js):

**The long version:**

I want to create a jQuery extension that adds a progress method to the $.ajax object and which works with IE8 & IE9's XDomainRequest object.

Currently, using the above plugins, I can only define progress event callback handlers for XMLHttpRequest objects.

However, XDomainRequest also provides an onprogress event. I basically need a wrapper for XDomainRequest. Eg. progressEvent.length would correspond to xdr.responseText.length.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I worked this out. I ended up forking [ajaxHooks](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks) which implements XDomainRequest via an ajax transporter.

I added support for an onprogress event callback named "progress" which can be defined with the original ajax object.

As per the W3C Standard, progressEvent.lengthComputable = false because we can't get the content length, and so progressEvent.total = 0;

See example below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var download_url = YOUR_URL;

    $.ajax({

        url: download_url,
        cache: false,
        progress: function(jqXHR, progressEvent) {

            console.log(progressEvent.loaded);

        }
    })
});
```

See my [ajaxHooks fork](https://github.com/rowandh/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js) here.

Comment: Excellent , can you handle the part of the repsonse you got? what is contained in the progressEvent?

Comment: Progress event is defined as `var progressEvent = {lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0};`

The only field that changes is 'loaded', because the content length is not computable (and so total = 0).