# AJAX/PHP asynchronous calculations

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am currently planning an Achievements system for my project. Achievements will be unlocked when the user actually visits the Achievements page, and any uncompleted ones will have their progress shown.

It may take some time to calculate some of the achievements' progress. I came up with this idea, but I have no idea how to go about implementing it, or if it's even possible:

- JavaScript requests achievements data via AJAX
- PHP starts calculating achievement progress
- For each achievement, a line is written to the output stream, of the form `ID:progress`
- JavaScript receives each line and shows the progress for the given achievement

How would I go about having AJAX read the `responseText` line-by-line as it arrives, rather than all at once at the end?

---

Additionally, if possible, I'd like for PHP to be threaded like so:

- For each achievement:

  - If there are more than N "threads", wait for one to finish
  - Fork off a thread to calculate the current achievement and echo the result line

Is such a thing possible in PHP?

---

Or am I just going about this completely the wrong way? Should I just send an AJAX request for each group of achievements? Or one per achievement? What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: Where's the performance bottleneck exactly? If computing a single achievement is relatively fast, issuing one ajax request per achievement sounds okay. Also, have you considered a cron job? (Downside: users wouldn't be able to see their achievements in real time).

Comment: @bfavaretto Most of them will be near-instant, but there may be a few of them that take longer due to needing to collect and process more complex data. I have played other games that use cron to update achievements, and I hated it. "I want my achievements *now*", I would say.

Comment: I figured you would. This might interest you, it seems to be possible to read a partial responseText, at least in some browsers: http://www.kylescholz.com/blog/2010/01/progressive_xmlhttprequest_1.html.

Comment: I think you really should split this up in two questions, one on the line-by-line ajax and one on the thread pool in PHP

Comment: This is too broad. Divide your problems.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this in modern ES5 browsers by using a combination of [XHR2 Progress Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) on the client and [HTTP Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) on the server - [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789703/how-to-write-javascript-in-client-side-to-receive-and-parse-chunked-response-i) goes into more detail.

Personally, I would say this approach is a little over-engineered.  If it's going to take less than a couple of seconds to fetch the player achievements the first time (presuming you will cache it for subsequent requests in a given time period) then I would just make the player wait whilst they download and look to optimise this once I had enough users to warrant it :)