# Handling chunked responses at high-level in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework-2.0

In case of slow server side actions, it is a good idea that the server could return a chunked response, so that the user experience is better, for example in the case of travel websites (look at Liligo.com)

Play! 2.0 as an excellent support for writing Actions which return chunked responses, however processing them at the client side is not straightforward.  As from the question : [How to write javascript in client side to receive and parse `chunked` response in time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789703/how-to-write-javascript-in-client-side-to-receive-and-parse-chunked-response-i) , jquery does not support working with chunked responses and working directly with low-level API might be dangerous for portability reasons

Is there any high-level javascript library which supports handling chunked/streamed responses?

Comment: This looks interesting, can you detail a little bit your answer?

Comment: have a look at Play's [Comet helper](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaComet). This might be what you're looking for.

Comment: This is too simplistic. My use case is that a javascript class calls a n action to retrieve a list of items and the list of items should be added to the class itself. The helper has no context, it's just a functin defined on the window