# Accessing Json file in streaming mode

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a 50 MB size json file that I am calling with PHP and it takes ages to load. Is there a way to stream it better than fully load it to the memory ?

if yes, the Json contains 2D arrays like this :

```
[[x,y,z],[x,y,z],.....],[[x,y,z],[x,y,z],.....]
```

how to call 50 2D arrays each time ?

Also is there a more efficient way than using json please tell me. I am using a webscraping JS scripts to collect data from websites and save them in a json file.

Comment: Dear Katarina, please provide us with a little insight of your file structure. You can post your php code here you know.

Comment: `$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);`
where `$json` is reading from file using `fopen` and `fread`

Comment: Are you serious?? Edit your post and put your code there not in the comment section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write javascript in client side to receive and parse \`chunked\` response in time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789703/how-to-write-javascript-in-client-side-to-receive-and-parse-chunked-response-i)