# How to send chunked HTTP request from client side javascript (not from Nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, http

I cannot find any way to start and manage a chunked **request** from client side javascript (whether it is a browser or React Native).

On the contrary Node.js provides the http module using which you can do the same task and `write()` the request body gradually.

My Question: Is there anyway to initiate a chunked HTTP request from client side javascript?

**Note:** That question is **NOT** about receiving a chunked **response**. I want to send a chunked **request**.

Example:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'some_url';
var body = 'The whole body data';
http.open('POST', url, true);

// Whatever the content type
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

// The whole data has to be ready and sent at once.
// How to stream the body? send it in chunks?
http.send(body);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write javascript in client side to receive and parse \`chunked\` response in time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789703/how-to-write-javascript-in-client-side-to-receive-and-parse-chunked-response-i)

Comment: No .. I do not want to receive a chunked **response**. I want to send a chunked **request**.